# What testing framework should I use to test node js modules?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, node-modules

I'm building a NodeJS module that needs some testing before publishing. I'm familiar with `Karma` and `Protractor` both using `Jasmine`. But they're both for testing on browsers which has nothing to do with my module (since it's meant to be core code of other applications/modules).

What is the best choice here? All I want to do is to call some functions of my module, feed it data and expect some outcome (return value). No interaction with browser needed.

Comment: maybe someone understood that you asked before doing due research. some people do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite stack to test nodejs is

- Mocha - test runner https://mochajs.org/
- Chai - assertion library http://chaijs.com/
- chai-as-promised - chai for promises https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised
- Sinon - spies and stubs http://sinonjs.org/
- supertests - integration tests  https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest

i hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. One more question though... Mocha reads all specs in `test` directory and I can't find a config file to configure that. I like to have my specs organized into sub-directories of `test`. Is that something that can be done in `mocha.opts`?

Comment: if you are planning into using something like gulp you can choose the files to test using gulp.src if you are using the cli  you can specify the test folder or a test file take a look at this tutorial. http://webapplog.com/tdd/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped.